# Problem Set template - explain this preamble to me?

Tags: environments, preamble

Can someone explain the following preamble to me? This is copied and pasted from a problem set template my T.A. made to help us typeset our homework... I'd really like to understand how it works. The thing that is stumping me the most is lines 5-6; why was it necessary to define a new TeX macro. Is it usually necessary to do so in LaTeX documents?

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt plus 1pt} 
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\indented#1{\list{}{}\item[]}
\let\indented=\endlist

\newcounter{questionCounter}
\newcounter{partCounter}[questionCounter]
\newenvironment{question}[2][\arabic{questionCounter}]{%
  \setcounter{partCounter}{0}%
  \vspace{.25in} \hrule \vspace{0.5em}%
  \noindent{\bf #2}%
  \vspace{0.8em} \hrule \vspace{.10in}%
  \addtocounter{questionCounter}{1}%
}{}
\renewenvironment{part}[1][\alph{partCounter}]{%
  \addtocounter{partCounter}{1}%
  \vspace{.10in}%
  \begin{indented}%
    {\bf (#1)} %
}{\end{indented}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28043/problem-set-template-explain-this-preamble-to-me/28047#28047) provides the means to correct the code, as well as introducing some improvements. Consider this answer merely an explanation as to way the original (faulty) code still compiled. The sequence of events that TeX followed are

1. `\def\indented#1{\list{}{}\item[]}`

   This defined the macro (not environment) `\indented` to take one argument. Since it is not used in the expansion, it will be discarded. For example, using only the above (and removing line 6 (given below in [2]), would gobble `something` when using `\indented{something}`.
2. `\let\indented=\endlist`

   This rewrites the definition of `\indented` as defined in [1] above, making [1] useless.
3. `\begin{indented} ... \end{indented}`

   Since the macro `\indented` is not undefined (or, defined) at this point - however meaningless its definition is, `\begin{indented}` is expanded to `\indented`, which is `\endlist`, which has no problem completing. I'm stumped by why TeX does not produce an error when trying to expand `\endindented` which is undefined. However, this could be a case where defining a start `\<myenv>` as the end `\end<myenv>` (like in [2]) may settle out the unmatched start-and-end of an environment `<myenv>`.
4. Finally, since the `indented` environment was never actually formally defined as anything, it didn't amount to anything in terms of the visible output.

Answer (score 6):

Line 6 should read

```
\let\endindented\endlist
```

These two lines are just a slightly more efficient way to say

```
\newenvironment{indented}
  {\begin{list}{}{}\item[]}
  {\end{list}}
```

When you do `\newenvironment{xyz}` you are really defining two commands: `\xyz` and `\endxyz`, which are executed (along with other commands) when LaTeX finds `\begin{xyz}` and `\end{xyz}`. Your TA is just showing off. :)

It's quite mysterious why the definition of `question` doesn't say

```
\refstepcounter{questionCounter}
```

instead of `\addtocounter{questionCounter}{1}`, thus inhibiting the possibility to say `\label{a-question}` in order to refer later to a question. It's quite mysterious also why not defining

```
\renewenvironment{part}[1][\alph{partCounter}]
  {\refstepcounter{partCounter}%
   \vspace{.10in}%
   \begin{list}{}{}\item[]\textbf{(#1)} }
  {\end{list}}
```

that would not need an auxiliary environment `indented`.

Also redefining `\part` doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: In short, the OP's TA *wanted* to show off, but failed to do so. ;-)

Comment: I suspect his name is Ben Lee User. ;-)

Comment: so is it not usually necessary to define TeX macros like that within a LaTeX document? even if it is more efficient, the main reason LaTeX exists is to provide an an abstracted TeX that makes page layout easier, right?

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to egreg's answer: The code lines

```
\newenvironment{indented}
  {\begin{list}{}{}\item[]}
  {\end{list}}
```

(as amended by egreg) define the `indented` environment as a one-item list (and issue the necessary `\item` command). This way, the spacing parameters of the new environment will conform to that of lists like `itemize` and `enumerate`. (The LaTeX standard classes use the same trick to define e.g. the `quote` environment.)